# creating dynamic div and making it editable but once writing into it cursor goes to start always

Tags: javascript

I am creating a dynamic div and making it editable using contentEditable but when I start writing into it cursor always goes to start. Why is it so? I am not getting it. Below code i am using on click.

```
function changeHeightWidthDiv(id)
{   
  // alert(id);
  $('#' + id).css('height','140px');
  $('#' + id).css('width','200px');

  $('#' + id).css('font-size','13px');
  $('#' + id).css('color','#000');

  $('#' + id).attr('contentEditable','true');
  $('#' + id).css('overflow-y','scroll');

  var token = "{{ csrf_token() }}"; 
  $.ajax({
     type:'GET',
     url:'/get-div-content',
     data:{_token:token,id:id},
     success:function(data){
     $('#' + data['divid']).html(data['content']);
     }
  });
}
```

But as soon as I start writing into it after 1 or 2 seconds cursor moves to the start position always which is very irritating. I think the issue is because I am also calling ajax to fill content in div every time click on it. so how can i solve that ?

Any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Please provide a minimal, reproducible example

Comment: It's not AJAX, but setting `.html(...)`. It doesn't make much sense to automatically refresh the content of an element a user is just typing to ...

Comment: on typing i am not doing that but on click i am calling ajax.Is there any other way i have to load content in box ?